# Excel 2016 VBA Replace Error Failing Inconsistently

Tags: vba, excel, office-2016

I am trying to loop through worksheets and remove file location prefixes using the Worksheet.Cells.Replace method in an Auto_Open function in Excel 2016 32-bit.

```
ws.Cells.Replace What:="'*:\*addin_name.xla*'!", Replacement:="", LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
        SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
```

The line above will occasionally cause a Run-time error '13': Type mismatch. Other times, the macro will run smoothly.

Has anyone experienced this behavior? Is there a good solution? If not, how could I structure the code to try the Replace method again 4 times if it causes the error?

Comment: Why retry *4 times*?

Comment: Curious about why Excel95's `Auto_Open` macro is favored over `Workbook_Open` event handler though.

Comment: Honestly, no idea why this helped, but here is what fixed it: Earlier in the code, I had used ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible. Changing that to Worksheets(ws_name).Visible = True fixed the problem for some reason.